# Change WordPress's login label, "Username"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On the default WordPress login page, how do you change the label, "Username", to something else?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/289583/133699

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think this is a better alternative to the previous answer.

```
function login_function() {
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'username_change', 20, 3 );
    function username_change( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) 
    {
        if ($text === 'Username') 
        {
            $translated_text = 'customLoginName';
        }
        return $translated_text;
    }
}
add_action( 'login_head', 'login_function' );
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the 20 and the 3 is in the filter.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Personally, I would move the filter callback outside of the if block, but that's just me. Either way, the 20 is for priority (used for the order of callback execution) and the 3 is the number of accepted arguments the callback takes.

Comment: Also, feel free to mark your own answer as accepted. I'm sure this will come in handy for anybody who has the same question you did.

Comment: In which file does this code go???   I tried it in functions.php but it did not work.  (The "Simple & Short Solution" below DID work in functions.php)

Answer (score 13):

**Simple & Short Solution**

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'register_text'  );
function register_text( $translating ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Your Custom Text',  $translating );
    return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works in the functions.php file exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It's worked for me. Using this functions.php code you can change any text.

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'register_text'  );
function register_text( $translating ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Your Custom Text',  $translating );
    return $translated;
}
```

Original Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502233/7186739

Answer (score 0):

Recently I get into the same situation, while I need to put the translated string to change this login label and I previously try using jQuery but didn't work so I use javascript as below:

```
function login_script_function() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed'); // to test DOM ready
    var label_user_login = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0];
    var label_user_pass = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[1];
    label_user_login.innerText = "<?php _e('User Name', 'text-domain'); ?>";
    label_user_pass.innerText = "<?php _e('Password', 'text-domain'); ?>";
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'login_head', 'login_script_function' );
```

I'm using this with the custom plugin and add the string translation with e.g. [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) or [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)