# wordpress change the default label "Username" to artist name

Tags: wordpress

I want that in the registration form instead of writing label "Username", I shall write the label "Artist". I have referred to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825865/change-wordpresss-login-label-username) But can't get it to work. I have shown my registration form in frontend using plugin theme my login.

Here is my code

```
if ($pagenow=='wp-login.php') { 
  add_filter( 'gettext', 'user_email_login_text', 20, 3 );
  function user_email_login_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ($translated_text == 'Username') {
    $translated_text = 'Artist Name';
    }

    return $translated_text;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code from the link you posted and it worked for me. That works specifically for "wp-login.php". Are you using something different than the default login? If so please provide more details.

Comment: yes i have added the registration form in frontend eg :  abc.com/register

Comment: Can you post relevant code snippet? I think I can make the correct adjustments to make it work.

Comment: I have used the same code as mentioned in above link but that din't worked for me. I have edited my question and added the code

Comment: Can you post the php for your register page?